# How to only transmit data through websocket if different from previous transmission

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, closures

I have a built a simple web application using NodeJS + Express, the request and socket.io modules to get JSON data from an external API and then transmit it using a websocket to the client.

What I would like to do is only transmit through the websocket if the externally requested JSON data has changed.

I cannot figure out how to add this condition with the code I have come up with so far:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 setInterval(function () {
  request({
   url: url,
   json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
   var senddata = JSON.stringify(body.result).toLowerCase();
   if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    socket.emit('result', senddata);
   }
  })
 }, 3000)
});
```

Comment: What have you tried?  It seems like storing the most recently sent data would be a good first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the last data for each socket in an object, then compare it with `senddata`:

```
var lastData = {};  //declare an object
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 setInterval(function () {
  request({
   url: url,
   json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
   var senddata = JSON.stringify(body.result).toLowerCase();
   if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    if (senddata !== lastData[socket.id]) {  //compare senddata with last data
     lastData[socket.id] = senddata;   //store new last data
     socket.emit('result', senddata);
    }
   }
  })
 }, 3000)
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How easy was that! This is pretty close to what I had tried but did not realise there was a socket.ID - I had fooled around with closures and callbacks and got very confused. Thank you for helping me out, I've only just started JS and am certainly not a developer/programmer by trade. Much appreciated.